# How to execute "-NoNewWindow" parameter in powershell v4

Tags: powershell, powershell-v4.0

I have used following command for my automation task. But it is throwing exception like below,

> parameter set cannot be resolved

**Command I used:**

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $code -verb RunAs
```

How to run the powershell commands in same command prompt ? and how to track that logs.

Comment: `-Verb` is not compatible with `-NoNewWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Each `-Verb` and `-NoNewWindow` parameters belong to different parameter sets of [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-4.0) cmdlet. For more information about parameter sets, read

```
Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters
```

and see [*Cmdlet Parameter Sets*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd878348(v=vs.85).aspx) in the [*Cmdlet Parameters*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/Library/ms714433(VS.85).aspx) MSDN article.

Observe the following self-explicating results:

```
PS D:\PShell> $y=(Get-Command Start-Process).ParameterSets
PS D:\PShell> $y.Count
2
PS D:\PShell> $y.Name
Default
UseShellExecute
PS D:\PShell> Compare-Object $y[0].Name $y[1].Name

InputObject     SideIndicator
-----------     -------------
UseShellExecute =>
Default         <=


PS D:\PShell> Compare-Object $y[0].Parameters.Name $y[1].Parameters.Name

InputObject            SideIndicator
-----------            -------------
Verb                   =>
Credential             <=
LoadUserProfile        <=
NoNewWindow            <=
RedirectStandardError  <=
RedirectStandardInput  <=
RedirectStandardOutput <=
UseNewEnvironment      <=


PS D:\PShell>
```